# Returning first letter when it is language specific character

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I have problem with returning first letter from string, when that letter is language specific character.

Reason of that situation is simple: specific character saved in string takes more than one character, and decoding takes place only on display in html with right coding.

When i try do this on php, smarty (truncate to first character), or even mysql i have only part of that letter coded in UTF (for example: � instead of real language specific character).

Is there any way to do this right?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [multibyte string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php). For example here you can use [mb_substr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php).

```
$first_char = mb_substr($s, 0, 1, 'UTF-8');
```

Here I am assuming you are using UTF-8.